# Custom UITableViewCell using UIAppearance proxy

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiappearance, uiaccessoryview

I would like to set a custom image for all the UITableViewCell accessory view in my app. I've tried using this code:

```
[[UITableViewCell appearance] setAccessoryView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"table-arrow.png"]]];
```

but it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating custom appearance selector in UITableViewCell category. Here's an example implementation:

.h:

```
- (void)setAccessoryViewImage:(UIImage *)image UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
```

.m:

```
- (void)setAccessoryViewImage:(UIImage *)image {
    self.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
}
```

And than you can configure all your cells using proxy object:

```
[[UITableViewCell appearance] setAccessoryViewImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"table-arrow.png"]];
```

Comment: Genius, didn't realize it was so easy to add UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTORs to views.

Answer (score 1):

// try this

```
   cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
   UIImageView *imgArrow = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 15)] ;
   imgArrow.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"table-arrow.png"];
   cell.accessoryView = imgArrow;
   [imgArrow release];
   imgArrow = nil;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I need to do that using the Apperance Proxy in order to avoid performing this operation for each single screen controller in my app.